# Creating the same method with different arguments

Tags: c#

I have created two methods, Radioactive_Sources, with the same name but different arguments because they are used for different purposes. One needs only two arguments and the other uses six arguments. How can I use these two methods when I call it in different class as I try it by below ways

```
namespace DABRAS_Software
{
  ...
  public DefaultConfigurations()
  {

ListOfSources = new List<Radioactive_Sources>(?) ; two arguments
ListOfSources_2 = new List<Radioactive_Sources>(?) ; six arguments
  .....

--------------------------------
namespace DABRAS_Software
{
[Serializable]
public class Radioactive_Source
{
  ....
 #region Constructor
 public Radioactive_Source(string _Name, string _SerialNumber, string _Description, RadiationType _Type, EnergyBand _E, ulong _HalfLife, string _CertDate, int _CertActivity) 
 {
    this.Name = _Name;
    this.SerialNumber = _SerialNumber;
    this.Description = _Description;
    this.SourceType = _Type;
    this.HalfLife = _HalfLife;
    this.CertificationDate = _CertDate;
    this.CertifiedActivity = _CertActivity;
    this.Energy_Band = _E;
 }

 public Radioactive_Source(string _Name,RadiationType _Type)
 {
   this.Name = _Name;
   this.SourceType = _Type;
 }


#endregion
```

.............

Comment: @InseokBeak you need to understand the difference between [Method Overloading](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx) and `Class Constructors` where are you creating the Property `Name, SerialNumber,...etc` understand what Generics are in regards to List<T> where `T` in your case is a `Class` please show all relevant code.

Comment: Those are not mere or regular methods; they are the constructors.  Using a different number of args doesnt make it a different Type.  What you have is just 2 ways to create an instance of the same thing.  You probably want inheritance

Comment: You don't have two methods called Radioactive_Source.  You have one class with two constructors, which is different.

Comment: You have two constructors that accept different parameters, that is fine. Those constructors are not being called when you create a `List<T>` of the `Radioactive_Source` class. They will only be called when you instantiate the class itself, for example if you called `ListOfSources.Add(new Radioactive_Source(name, type));`. What are you trying to accomplish? It isn't quite clear from your question.

Comment: ...and even if you had one Type inheriting the other or from an abstract base class, it is not necessary to store them in different collections: the classes could include a property to tell one from the other

Comment: You can't restrict the list to contain items that were constructed with a certain number of arguments. If you want to do what you are suggesting, I'd create 2 different subclasses.

Comment: ListOfSources = new List<Radioactive_Source>();
ListOfSources2 = new List<Radioactive_Source>();

Answer (score 1):

Eh, do you mean *six items*, (since `ListOfSources` is in fact a collection, `List<Radioactive_Sources>`) not *six arguments*? If it's your case then

```
  ListOfSources = new List<Radioactive_Sources>() {
    // Put as many items as you want here
    new Radioactive_Sources(), //TODO: put the right constructors here
    new Radioactive_Sources(), 
  };
```

Comment: I think the OP wants 2 different Types based on: `because they are used for different purpose`l it looks like they are trying to store the 2 arg version in a different collection than the 6 arg version.

Comment: Kudos for noticing the confusion between constructing a Radioactive_Source and a List.

Answer (score 0):

The list object will just hold an array or list of objects of radioactive class. You need to initialize each radioactive object individually with whatever constructor method you like and add it to the list.
Something like this.

```
Radioactive obj1=new Radioactive(2 or 6 or whatever args);

mylist.add(obj1);
```